# Psychopy how to solve TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, colors, psychopy

**OS** (e.g. Win10): macOS 10.15.7

**PsychoPy version** (e.g. 1.84.x): 21.1.2

**Standard Standalone? (y/n)** y

**What are you trying to achieve?:**
I'm a beginner in programming so I'm using a builder to create the online experiment, Magnitude estimation of lightness between two circles, through psychopy.

**What did you try to make it work?:**
magnitude estimation of lightness between reference stimulus(white) and random order test stimulus.

**What specifically went wrong when you tried that?:**
Experiment stop at the random point during the 27inch routine. When I made multiple loops it stopped at the first loop when I made a single loop, it didn't move to the next routine, it stopped at a random point in the routine.
And show the same error all the time. I can't figure out the reason. Please help me :(

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/woojaejung/Desktop/Pilot_experiment/Psychopy/capstonePilot_lastrun.py", line 596, in <module>
    win.flip()
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.6/psychopy/visual/window.py", line 1044, in flip
    thisStim.draw()
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.6/psychopy/visual/shape.py", line 394, in draw
    GL.glColor4f(*self._fillColor.render('rgba1'))
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.6/psychopy/colors.py", line 346, in render
    adj = np.clip(self.rgb * self.contrast, -1, 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```